# Magento Order Shipment Email not sending - Instead we are sending the Shipment Update Email

Tags: shipment

We are using laravel to send our orders to and from our warehouse using the Magento API.

I am having issues sending the Order Shipment email, instead, the customers are getting the "Order Update" email that says their order is complete.

The code below add the comment into the comment history and says the customer was "Notified" but the email is not going out.

Any ideas?

```
try {
    $shipment = $client->call('sales_order_shipment.create', ["orderIncrementId" => $data->channel_order_code]);

    if (strlen($data->tracking) > 12) {
        $client->call('sales_order_shipment.addTrack', ['shipmentIncrementId' => $shipment, 'carrier' => "usps", 'title' => $data->channel, 'trackNumber' => $data->tracking]);
    } else {
        $client->call('sales_order_shipment.addTrack', ['shipmentIncrementId' => $shipment, 'carrier' => "fedex", 'title' => $data->channel, 'trackNumber' => $data->tracking]);
    }
    try{
        $client->call('order_shipment.addComment', ['shipmentIncrementId' => $shipment,'comment' => 'Your order has shipped with tracking number '.$data->tracking, 'email' => true]);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Please flow below steps:**

**Method:**

```
sales_order_shipment.create (SOAP V1)
```

Allows you to create a new shipment for an order.

**Aliases:**

```
order_shipment.create
```

**Arguments:**

1. string   sessionId   (Session ID)
2. string   orderIncrementId (Order    increment ID)
3. array    itemsQty (Array of orderItemIdQty (optional))
4. string   comment (Shipment comment (optional))
5. int  email (Send email flag (optional))
6. int  includeComment (Include comment in email flag (optional))

**API Code:**

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$orderIncrementId = '100000006';
$itemsQty = array();

$result = $proxy->call($sessionId,'order_shipment.create',array($orderIncrementId,$itemsQty,null,true,false)); //$orderIncrementId, $itemsQty = array(),$comment = null, $email = false, $includeComment = false
```